# Bind slave creating domain without any records

Tags: linux, bind, replication, slave

i have the same version of Bind running on two different host. When a new domain is created it is also created on the slave but there are no records within the domain.

I am not sure what i need to do to fix this or what information is required.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

If your server is the slave for a domain, it will keep the informations from the master (if it has the rights to do that). So it is normal, at the start of bind that the bases are empty. Immediately, the slave server ask to the master all the records concerning the zone. Then it is available to answer to clients.

If it doesn't works, check your bind logs : you will see some informations like 'AFXR error', 'connection closed'. Check on the master too, if you have access : there is maybe a filter to fobidden zone transferts.